# Pegar o valor do ID e jogar em uma variável

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Bom o meu problema é que estou trabalhando com tabela Pai x Filho e quando crio uma nova linha, todos os inputs recebem IDs diferentes e precisava passar o o que tem dentro do ID para uma variável

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" id="Total___1" name="Total_Soma">
var idtostring = "Total___1"
```

Com isso eu já resolvo meu problema, mas eu acho que não vejo possibilidade pra isso

OBS: Eu não crio o ID, ele se adequa com a linha, portanto não adianta falar que é apenas fazer as funções para esse id, pois eles mudam e são ***N*** possibilidades.

Comment: Matheus até editei a resposta agorinha mesmo, só para colocar o ID em uma variável antes de fazer o console.log direto com o ID, acho que fica mais próximo ainda do que vc está precisando ai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz um `forEach` pegando os `ids`. A ressalve é deixar o script depois do script que faz o `loop` dos elementos que recebem o `ID`, ou então sempre rodar esse script junto com a função que faz o `loop` e cria o `ID`, só esse script tem que vir no final dessa função.

*OBS: Eu coloquei nos inputs dentro da tabela o atributo `[data-input]` apenas para facilitar para pegar apenas esses inputs em particular.*

```js
let meuID = document.querySelectorAll('[data-input]');

meuID.forEach( (e) => {
    let qualID = e.id;
    console.log(qualID)
})
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-input type="text" id="n1" name="Total_Soma">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-input type="text" id="n2" name="Total_Soma">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-input type="text" id="n3" name="Total_Soma">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-input type="text" id="n4" name="Total_Soma">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Vai me ajudar muito!!

Comment: @MatheusATAR sem problemas meu caro fico feliz em ter ajudado